# Incomplete code completion for Sublime Text 2 for Python

Tags: python, intellisense

I want my Sublime Text 2 for Python to have code completion. I already installed "SublimeCodeIntel" and it works for some things but not for showing methods of an object.

```
import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader


dirPath = "C:/RealPython/Course materials/Chapter 12/Practice files"
fullPath = os.path.join(dirPath, "Pride and Prejudice.pdf")
pdfReader = PdfFileReader(file(fullPath, "rb"))
blah = pdfReader.[APPEAR INTELISENSE STUFF HERE]
```

I'm on Win8 64 and using the latest of Python 2.